# Threads and termination of main

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have a small question regarding Threads.

(That code is just for illustration for my question and does not make real sense)

```
public int recursiveMethod(int val, int depth){

if ( depth < 0}{
return sequentialMethod(val)
}

Integer [] buffer = new Integer [2]; 

Thread child1 = new Thread(new Task(val,buffer, 0, depth -1))
Thread child2 = new Thread(new Task(val,buffer, 1, depth -1))

try{
child1.join(); 
child2.join(); }
catch(InterruptException e){
..}

return buffer[0] + buffer[1]
}


public class Task implements Runnable {
public Task(val, buffer, index, depth){
constructor... 
}

public void run{
 buffer[index] = recursiveMethod(val, depth)
return; }
```

This is just a small code example (does not have a sense but illustration)  with which I want to illustrate what I have been working one. (It is actually not that important but it is just splitting up a calculation into subparts, storing the result of these in buffers)

So in my code from a root thread I recursively call the `recursiveMethod()` that again creates other threads that again call that same method... All parent threads are joined to their child threads.

For my real code which is a bit heavier ( parallel matrix multiplication of square matrices)  I get a correct result at the end pretty fast but I face a problem that I think is weird:

Even though I join all parent Threads to their children the program in my IDE still runs for a couple second ( 0.5s - 1.5s ) after the final result ( so the one call of the recursive method that has the original depth) is returned. So there is something still running.

I just do not understand since, as I understood it the join method just takes care of that first all Threads have to dead until the final result can be returned.

If something is unclear I am happy to answer and clarify

Would be very happy for an answer

Thanks in advance
Jonas

Comment: Re, "if something is unclear..." You haven't shown the code that makes the "root" call to `recursiveMethod()`, and you haven't shown what it does after that "root" call returns. Also, you say you are running it in an IDE, but you haven't said _which_ IDE, or what command you use to run the program. Also, is it possible that your program calls any GUI framework routine that could create an event dispatch thread or a timer thread?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I can't answer because you haven't shown enough code for anybody to be able to know what's really going on in your program, but I have a suggestion for you.

Half of the threads in your program do nothing but create other threads and then wait. Creating threads is expensive. Why not put those threads to work? Instead of creating a new thread to do the work of `child2` while the calling thread does nothing but wait, Let the calling thread do the work. E.g., Like this:

```java
   Thread child1 = new Thread(new Task(...));
// Thread child2 = new Thread(new Task(...));   // Don't do this.
   Task    task2 = new Task(...);               // Do this instead.

   child1.start();
// child2.start();    // And, Don't do this.
   task2.run();       // Do this instead.

   try {
       child1.join();
   } catch (...) {
       ...
   }
```

Your program should produce the same result, using only half as many threads.

---

P.S.; For extra credit, instead of using bare `Thread`s, consider whether your program could be made to work with a [*thread pool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava